# Is there a notation for least/greatest element of partially ordered set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, notation

> **Definition.** Let $P=(S,\leq)$ be a partially ordered set. If it is true that
>   $$(\exists s_0\in S)\ (\forall s\in S)\ \ s\leq s_0$$
>   then $s_0$ is said to be a greatest element of $S$.

Of course, if a greatest element exists, it is *the* unique greatest element, and coincides with the unique maximal element, $\max S$.  For this reason, the usefulness of such a notation is debatable but the question nevertheless stands. If anything, one could simply write $\operatorname{ges} S =\max S $, or $\operatorname{ges S}$ does not exist etc, for example $\operatorname{ges} S$ does  not exist etc.<sup>[1]</sup>

- Is there some common notation for the least/greatest element of a set?

(Used simply for the sake of an example, not a suggestion: ges – greatest element of set.)

---

[1] Example: $P=(\{1,3,7\},|)$, $\max_1 S= 3$, $\max_2 S= 7$, $\operatorname{ges} S$ does not exist. Therefore, any notation used for maximal elements is ill-suited for the greatest element in this case.

Comment: Greatest element doesn't exists means that ${\rm ges}S$ is ill defined, there is no point talking about this, $\max S$ in your example should be $\{3,7\}$ because the moment you add the $_{1,2}$ you get order on them, which is not unique unless there is unique, there are no, thus $\max_{1,2} S$ are ill defined

Comment: @Holo "Greatest element doesn't exists means that gesS is ill defined, there is no point talking about this". I understand. Nevertheless, one can and very often does write $\lim \limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ does not exist, instead of writing the limit of the function $f(x)$ as x... does not exist. It is a matter of convenience if anything else. (1/2)

Comment: @Holo "$\max S$ in your example should be $\{3,7\}$ because the moment you add the 1,2 you get order on them, which is not unique unless there is unique, there are no, thus $\max_{1,2} S$ are ill defined". Could you elaborate? The indices $1$ and $2$ are meant to be taken as arbitrary; there is no comparison intended. To take $\max S = \{3,7\}$ does not sit well with me at least on a first glance because it (to me, a beginner) supposes by the definition of a maximal element that I'm comparing $\{3,7\}$, a set, to the elements of $\{1,3,7\}$. (2/2). Thanks.

Comment: let me give you an example. Let $P=(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N), \le^*)$ where $a\le^* b\iff a=b$. What will $\max_1\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$ be? What about $\max_n\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$?

Comment: About the first part, I would say that it is abuse of notation more than anything

Comment: @Holo About your quite reasonable example: I would probably write that the **set** of maximums of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is $\{x| x \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\}$; calling the set itself the maximum still wouldn't sit well with me. But I take the spirit of your point into account. That said, when the set of maximums is finite "my" notation works (with an extension for countable cases too). Regardless of all of the above, I thus assume you have also not come across any notation that differentiates between maximal elements and a greatest element? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88748/discussion-between-holo-and-linear-christmas).

Answer (score 2):

I’ve commonly seen the following:

$0, \bot$- minimal element in a partial ordered set

$1, \top$- maximal element

Comment: Also common are $\bot$ and $\top$, respectively.

Comment: Indeed. I updated my answer with these.

Comment: If I'd wish to specify the set, I'd assume $0_{S}$ and $\bot(S)$ are used? Also: did you mean least and greatest element instead? Otherwise it misses the point somewhat; I would like to write $\bot(A)$ does not exist while $\max_1\{S\} = 2$, $\max_2\{S\} = 5$ for instance.

Comment: The super scripts could be used to specify the set, of course. If either one of those exist, they are the least or greatest respectively. I’m making an abuse of notation.

Comment: "If either one of those exist, they are the least or greatest respectively." A partially orded set can have two maximal elements, and no greatest element, hence the comment.